# populate boolean values in checkbox in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have following fields Db table , I want populate those values in check boxes

```
    public Nullable<bool> Report_Users { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Innovation_Discussion_User { get; set; }
```

this is specific row in above table

[image]

I'm expecting ,

1. **empty** check box if Values are `NULL` or `FALSE`
2. **checked** check box if values are `TRUE`

this is the syntax I've been used ,

```
            @Html.CheckBox("Report User", Model == null ? false : (Model.Report_Users == Model.Report_Users ? true : false), new { @value = "false"  }) Report User
             &nbsp; 
            @Html.CheckBox("Innovation Discussion User", Model == null ? false : (Model.Innovation_Discussion_User == Model.Innovation_Discussion_User ? true : false), new { @value = "false"  }) Innovation Discussion User
```

but this seems not poplate correct values,

both check boxes showing checked always

[image]

Comment: You cannot use a checkbox for  a `nullable bool`. A checkbox has only 2 states (check/unchecked - or true/false) whereas `bool?` has 3 states (true/false/null). Make the property `bool` (not nullable) or use `EditorFor(m => m.Report_Users)` whicj will generate a dropdownlist with 3 values.

Comment: @kez Try the follwoing `Model?.Report_Users ?? false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GetValueOrDefault()` on nullable types, this will return false for null values as false is the default value for a `bool`.

```
@Html.CheckBox("Report User", 
    Model.Report_Users.GetValueOrDefault()) Report User
```

Comment: what if `Model` is `null` ?

Comment: @tchelidze I can't understand why the model would be null in the first place. Can you? :)

Comment: Don't set `new { @value = "false"  }` - `CheckBox()` generates 2 inputs, a checkbox with `value="true"` and a hidden input with `value="false". This code would only ever post back `false` no matter if it was checked or not

Comment: @hutchonoid have you never had scenario, while developing, where `Model` is null ? In this case `Model.Report_Users` can also be `null` and this will cause `NullReference`

Comment: @tchelidze - `.GetValueOrDefault()` cannot throw a NullReference  - it returns false when the value if `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `@value=false` was just copied from the answer, removed now. :)

Comment: @tchelidze I've not had that before, if a view has a model I would always return one. If there wasn't I would have thought it would have been a bug in the first place IMO. It would create a lot of work for me if I had to start doing `@Model == null` before accessing every property in every view.

Comment: @tchelidze Yours does work though so is a correct answer too. +1 :)

Comment: @hutchonoid I agree with you, `Model == null` indicates some bug. I have no big experience in developing `MVC` apps. thanks you ))

Comment: Inf MVC, you might check if `Model==null` once at the top of your view, just to show a "proper" error in case there's some other bug (rather than useless nullref error), but you wouldn't put it in front of every property access.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
@Html.CheckBox("Report User",Model?.Report_Users ?? false)
```